# objective-c, How to add a UITextField on UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to wait for a username input by alert dialog, how to add UITextField on UIAlertView

Comment: For iOS7 see [my answer for a login alert][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19051713/993494

Answer (score 8):

This has changed since iOS5. You can now create a UIAlertView with a style.

UIAlertView now has a property - `alertViewStyle` that you can set to one of the enum values

- UIAlertViewStyleDefault
- UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput
- UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput
- UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput

Once you've created the alert view, you set it style and display it. After dismissing the alert, you can access the contents of the fields using the `textFieldAtIndex:` property of the alert view.

Answer (score 6):

Like this :

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter  Login" message:@"\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Sign In", nil];

myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
myTextField.placeholder=@"Enter User Name";
[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
myTextField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;

// myTextField.layer.cornerRadius=5.0; Use this if you have added QuartzCore framework

[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
[myAlertView show];
[myAlertView release];
```

Comment: If using iOS5 or later, there is now built in support for this feature.

Comment: @Abizern I haven't tried it with iOS5 , but if you have code & if you wish you can put the code for iOS5 too so one can get the alert for both versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter  Login" message:@"\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Sign In", nil];

```
    myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
    myTextField.placeholder=@"Enter User Name";
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    myTextField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    // myTextField.layer.cornerRadius=5.0; Use this if you have added QuartzCore framework
        [myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
    [myAlertView show];
    [myAlertView release];
```

Hope this will solve your problem.......