# iOS multiple text fields on a UIAlertview In IOS 7

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview, textfield

So the new iOS 7 has come out and I'm trying to add multiple textFields and labels to the UIAlertviews. I need three. I've been trying to add them as subviews and that doesn't work anymore. I have also tried to add multiple lines with the UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput but it only seems to return one text field.

I need to add in labels to show them what to enter as well. Is there a way to accomplish this task with the new iOS 7?

Comment: Please show your code. Did the code previously work in iOS6?

Comment: You can't add subviews to a `UIAlertView`. That's not its purpose. You can make use of the standard support for 1 or 2 text fields. Instead of adding labels, set the text field's `prompt` property.

Comment: Ok thanks I saw that you could do it on iOS 5. I guess they took it out on iOS 7. I'll just make another view and add it as as a subview thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14):

The only solution i found using UIAlertView with more than one text field in iOS7 is for login only.

use this line to initialize your alertView

```
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
```

and this to grab the users input:

```
user = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
pw = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1].text
```

For other purposes than login view the other threads like this on: [UIAlertView addSubview in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7)

Comment: Yeuh thanks for the answer I ended up making a custom subview that looked like a uiAlertView.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is great and also points to how utterly useless UIAlertView is... the message from Apple is clear: go and write code. It's the most productive thing you can do.

Answer (score 12):

You can change *accessoryView* to any own *customContentView* in a standard alert view in iOS7

```
[alertView setValue:customContentView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
```

Note that you must call this before *[alertView show]*.

Simplest illustrating example:

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[av setValue:v forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[av show];
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If you want to add just two textfields to your `UIAlertView`, you can use `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput` and modify the textfields as follows:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Some Title" message:@"Some Message." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:@"No, thanks", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].secureTextEntry = NO; //Will disable secure text entry for second textfield.
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].placeholder = @"First Placeholder"; //Will replace "Username"
[alert textFieldAtIndex:1].placeholder = @"Second Placeholder"; //Will replace "Password"
[alert show];
```

Afterwards, in the UIAlertView delegate, you can simply get the text using:

```
text1 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
text2 = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1].text;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the details about the secureEntry and placeholder text. Much nicer answer because of this :-)

Comment: this is not working in ios 11. Is there any idea that someone could suggest it.