# In UIAlertView trying to view two textfield. Its showing error bounds of the array of text fields iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

Hi I'm trying to view two text fields in `UIAlertView` but its showing error. I have used the below code to view the text fields.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!"
                                                     message:@"Please enter your details:"
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    UITextField * name = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    name.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    name.placeholder = @"Enter your name";

    UITextField * phone = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
    phone.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    phone.placeholder = @"Enter your phone";

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

I have used the above code to view two textfileds but I'm getting like. **'textFieldIndex (1) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'**

Please tell me where I'm doing wrong in the above code and please tell me show to resolve this issue.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886048/ios-multiple-text-fields-on-a-uialertview-in-ios-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `UIAlertView.h` file

> /* Retrieve a text field at an index - raises NSRangeException when
>   textFieldIndex is out-of-bounds.     The field at index 0 will be the
>   first text field (the single field or the login field), the field at
>   index 1 will be the password field. */

```
- (UITextField *)textFieldAtIndex:(NSInteger)textFieldIndex NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

Do like this:

```
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

UITextField * name = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
name.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
name.placeholder = @"Enter your name";

UITextField * phone = [alert textFieldAtIndex:1];
phone.secureTextEntry = NO;
phone.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
phone.placeholder = @"Enter your phone";
```